# Add an Attachment to a ListInstance Data Node?

Tags: sharepoint, attachment, moss

Is it possible to add an attachment within the ListInstance when specifying Default records for a list when creating it with a Feature in MOSS?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to do this via code within the [FeatureActivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfeaturereceiver.featureactivated.aspx) method of the feature receiver.